# How do we determine ramp length and angle required for vehicle access to an elevated surface?

Tags: garage, angle, clearance, ramp, car

I'm wondering if there's any mathematical or scientific way to determine the car ramp's length and angle provided car's ground clearance and height of garage floor from the road.

I'm looking to find the shortest ramp length for my car to climb but the angle should be just right for the car to climb without scraping the bumper.

I have very little space, so the shortest length is something I care about.

[image]

Please note that I couldn't find angle of departure/arrival for my car.

Car's ground clearance(Lowest point of the car from the ground) is 170mm.

The height of garage floor from the ground is 14.5 inches

The total length of garage is 20 feet.

Here is [car-specific information](https://www.toyotabharat.com/showroom/glanza/#specifications).

[image]

[image]

P.S

- As of now garage ramp length is 4 feet 10 inches. I want to shorten the length as much as possible
- My car's tire pressure 30 PSI and I maintain that.
- Whenever I park my car in the garage , Only the driver will be in so no extra load.
- Here's the car size

  ```
   Length*Width*Height:3990*1745*1500 mm3
  ```
- Car's wheelbase( Centre of front axle to centre of rear axle ) is 2520 mm
- The climate around the residence is Tropical Savannah so no snow :)  Usually highly humid coastal area climate

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148947/discussion-on-question-by-king-how-do-we-determine-ramp-length-and-angle-require); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: With the desired result including mathematical and geometric formulas, This question may be better suited for Mathematics SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry

Comment: @Triplefault - Can we migrate this question to geometry ?

Comment: Any answer here is a guess. The math does not consider variables such as tire pressure or varying ride height dependant on the weight of the occupant/s of the vehicle, (It is unknown what the ride height is when the vehicle is occupied.) Even approach speed and spring compression rates will effect the height. Heck even the ambient temperature can be a factor, as it will have an effect on the tire pressure. ( tire pressure and thus size will be different after driving and building heat as opposed to the vehicle standing still for a period of time.) As a result the car may clear when entering th

Comment: What's the safest angle and length of the garage ramp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At given dimensions this drawing shows you would have  a INCH of clearance when the car is half way in the garage.

Using simple geometry it shows that a ramp length of 4 ft 11 inches the clearance would be 1 inch.
The slope is simple given by connecting the hight with length thus making a triangle with slope of 22 Dgr.

[image: drawing]

Comment: this would only work if you drive insanely slow perpendicularly from the street into the ramp with no extra weight compared to when you measured, and there's no snow on the drive that isn't on a cleared street, etc.

Comment: I've updated my question with accurate details. Basically I want to find out the shortest garage ramp length along with the garage ramp angle for the distance between ground and garage floor which is 14.5 inches for my car(Ground clearance is 170mm)

Comment: The shorter the length of the Ramp the higher will be the slope and the lover will be the clearance.

Comment: It seems short-sighted to assume that only one car ever need pull in here. What if your car wrecks? What if a family member comes by? What if a delivery driver pulls in with his low-rider? Forget about your car, and design for a worst-case scenario.

Comment: @king see my updated info

Comment: @asinine - How do you say , I will have less than an inch of clearance.Any formula to back it up ?

Comment: @King it is geometry

Comment: This is, most likely, the answer to the question the OP asked. If it's practical in the real world, with the exceedingly exact conditions the OP stated being met every single time, is a whole different question and not the one asked.